# Playing audio on mouseover in Firefox with NoScript installed

Tags: firefox, audio, noscript

I am using Firefox Web browser with NoScript.

I want to hear pronunciation of words on a website such as: http://dictionary.reference.com/

A Straightforward solution is that I can uncheck *Forbid Audio / Video* under the *Embeddings* option. This would allow me to download the audio of pronunciation.

OR I can click on audio link under *Blocked Objects*.

but I want to hear it directly without downloading it. I have a understanding that it has something to do with sfdict.com. (but I am not sure)

How it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option you refer to looks like it only applies to domains that are not trusted. When I whitelisted reference.com and sfdict.com the embedded player worked as intended.

You will want to whitelist those two domains to get the player to work inline.